# Wifi auto rejoin issues on Nexus 5 / Android 4.4

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5

Here's a problem I've been experiencing with my new Nexus 5:

I leave my home wifi (which I was connected to). I then go to work where there is a wifi network I've previously joined. However, my Nexus 5 won't automatically rejoin the work wifi. If I go to the wifi menu and try to tell it to connect.... it does nothing. It sees the network and says it has a good strong signal, but it simply won't connect to it. If I turn airplane mode on and off (or restart the phone), it will join the work wifi.

Same thing happens in reverse (leave work wifi, won't auto rejoin home wifi). Or if I just walk out of range of the wifi network and walk back into range of it.

I did not have this issue on Android 4.2.2 with my Galaxy Nexus.

Is there a way to fix this? Or is it some sort of software bug in Android 4.4?

Comment: This might be relevant: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58230

Comment: This might also be relevant (answer #13), might be because wifi profiles transferred from my Galaxy Nexus? https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61945#c13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this was an issue from Google's syncing of wifi profiles from older phones. For some reason, when my new Nexus 5 acquired the wifi profiles from my Galaxy Nexus, they exhibit this issue.

[The solution here worked](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61945#c13) but you must be rooted. You must delete all the wifi profile data (**requires root**) and then re-join the wifi networks again.

```
adb shell
$ su
# rm -r /data/misc/wifi/
# reboot
```

Then rejoin your wifi networks in the wifi manager. When you leave the range of the wifi and come back, it should reconnect as normal.